# Laravel Livewire Select Field gets empty on render, but array still holds the selected value

Tags: select

I have a strange behaviour on my Livewire Component Select Field,
I am using an array which expands on click on button "add item".
When I select in the  field on my form a value it gets selected but disappears after calling the change function in my livewire script.
If I select the value a second time it works.
What I have:
Blade:

```
     @foreach ($positions as $index => $position)
            <div class="col-sm-6" >
           <!-- abk -->
           <label for="pos ">&nbsp;</label><br>   <label for="auftrag">Auftrag:</label>
        @if(($positions[$index]['part_id']>0) && ($positions[$index]['part_id'] != 9999))
        @if(isset($positions[$index]['abks']) && count($positions[$index]['abks'])>0)
          <!-- true if there are abks -->
         <select class="form-control"   id="positions[{{$index}}]['abk_id']" wire:change="abkChanged({{$index}},$event.target.value)" >
                                               <option value="0" >-</option>
                                               @foreach($positions[$index]['abks'] as $abk)
                                                   <option value="{{$abk['id']}}">
                                                   {{$abk['auftragsnummer']}} -Fert.menge: {{$abk['fertigungsmenge']}} - geänd.: {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($abk['updated_at'])->format('d.m.Y - H:i') }}</option>
                                               @endforeach
                                               <option value="9999" >eigene Beschreibung</option>
                                           </select>
                                    @else
                                        <!-- todo what to do if there are no abks... -->


                                    @endif

                                @endif <!-- if part_id >0 & not 9999-->
                                    @if(isset($position['showabktext']) && $position['showabktext'] == 1)

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="positions[{{$index}}]['abktext']" wire:model="positions.{{$index}}.abktext" placeholder="ABK/AB # ..."/>
                                @endif
                                   @if (isset($position['abk_id'])) {{$position['abk_id']}}
                                     positions:   {{$positions[$index]['abk_id']}}
                                   @endif
  @endforeach
```

the Component:

```
public function partChanged($indexPosition) { //if part is selected
 //   dd($indexPosition); // holds $this->positions[$indexPosition]
    if($this->positions[$indexPosition]['part_id'] == 9999) { //own description
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showartikeltext']=1; //own artikelbezeichnung
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showlszustandtext']=1; //own bearbeitet nach zeichnung etc
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showabktext']=1; //own abk text

    } else { //part from db
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showartikeltext']=0;
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showlszustandtext']=0;
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['abks']= Abk::where('part_id','=',$this->positions[$indexPosition]['part_id'])->orderBy('updated_at')->get();//client_id
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showabktext']=0;
        if(empty($this->positions[$indexPosition]['abks'])|| count($this->positions[$indexPosition]['abks'])<1) {
            $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showabktext']=1;
        }
    }
    //zustand



}



public function abkChanged($indexPosition, $value) {
    $this->positions[$indexPosition]['abk_id'] = $value;
    if($this->positions[$indexPosition]['abk_id'] === 9999) {
        $this->positions[$indexPosition]['showabktext']=1;
    }


   // dd($this->positions[$indexPosition]['abk_id']);
 //   dd($this->positions);
 //dd($value);

}


public function addPos(){
    $counter = count($this->positions);
    $this->positions[] = ['position'=>$counter, 'part_id'=>0];

}

public function removePos($index){
    unset($this->positions[$index]); //lösche ag aus array
    $this->positions = array_values($this->positions); //reorder Array!

}
```

short for understanding what has to happen:
I select a client -> then render the clients parts  after selecting a part render the abks which belong to the parts.
And then select the abk.

Selecting a client and then selecting a part works perfectly - but if I select an abk the selection disappears ($positions.$index.['abk_id]) - but if I add another item  to the list (another part) the abk selection renders as expected. on the first item, if I select the second one same behaviour as before on the first one.

I think I have a id / name DOM problem but I can't see it...

Please help :(

Thank you!
Stev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... oh man what a baaad "bug", if I remove the Carbon->parse method from the Select field option it works as expected - I don't know why ... but it works now.